# Vue Watch not Triggering on Page Refresh/Reload

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a component which is hid based on the route which is active, it kicks off a function which is stored using vuex store.

It works as intended, the sidenav is hidden on login, logout, and register.

However, I noticed when I am on an authenticated page such as admin panel, or dashboard, etc, the component displays correctly, but when/if someone reloads the webpage, the component disappears, only to be displayed when clicking a link to another page.

**App.Vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <navbar />
        <sidenav v-show="sidenav_toggle" />
        <div class="row router-container">
            <div class="col router-row">

                <router-view/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import router from '@/router'

import axios from 'axios'
import AxiosStorage from 'axios-storage'

let sessionCache = AxiosStorage.getCache('localStorage');



import materializecss from '../static/css/main.css'
import materializejs from '../static/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js' 

import navbar from '@/components/navbar'
import sidenav from '@/components/sidenav'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
    sidenav:{
        show: false
    }
}

const mutations = {
    show_sidenav(state){
        state.sidenav.show = true
    },
    hide_sidenav(state){
        state.sidenav.show = false
    }
}

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state,
    mutations
})



export default {
    router,
    name: 'App',
    watch:{
        $route: function(){
            if(this.$route.path === '/login' || this.$route.path === '/logout' || this.$route.path === '/register'){
        store.commit('hide_sidenav')
        console.log('not authd')
            }else{
        store.commit('show_sidenav')
        console.log('authd')
            }
        },
        deep: true,
        immediate: true
    },
    computed: {
        sidenav_toggle(){
            return store.state.sidenav.show
        }
    },

    data: function(){
        return{
        }
    },
    components: {
        navbar,
        sidenav
    },
    methods: {


    },
    created: function(){

    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your watcher is not called if you land directly on the admin page because the `$route` property never changes (and watchers only watch for changes).

What you could do is move your watcher function in a method, and call this method in the `created` hook and in your watcher.

An even better way to do this would be to use vue-router [navigation-guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard)

Example:

```js
export default {
  // ...
  methods: {
    adaptSidebar(path) {
      if (['/login', '/logout', '/register'].includes(path)) {
        store.commit('hide_sidenav')
      } else {
        store.commit('show_sidenav')
      }
    },
  },
  beforeRouterEnter(from, to, next) {
    // As stated in the doc, we do not have access to this from here
    next(vm => {
      vm.adaptSidebar(to.path)
    })
  },
  beforeRouteChange(from, to, next) {
    this.adaptSidebar(to.path)
  },
}
```